# DataModel cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I couldn't find what the problem is. Logcat is saying :

> "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
> com.example.project.model.DataModel cannot be cast to
> java.util.ArrayList"

I tried different solutions but none worked:

- Parcelable
- @SuppressWarning

Could someone show me what is wrong in my code please?

**DataModel.Java**

```
public class DataModel implements Serializable {

    ArrayList<FeaturesModel> features;
    String title;

    public DataModel(ArrayList<FeaturesModel> featuresModels, String s) {
        features =featuresModels;
        title=s;
    }

    public ArrayList<FeaturesModel> getFeatures() {
        return features;
    }

    public void setFeatures(ArrayList<FeaturesModel> features) {
        this.features = features;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

**TableActivity.Java**

```
public class TableActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<DataModel> dataModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    EditText edtTableCount;
    Button btnCreateTable;
    TableAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recylerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_table);

        recylerView = findViewById(R.id.rvTables);

        btnCreateTable = findViewById(R.id.btnCreateTable);


        btnCreateTable.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            edtTableCount = findViewById(R.id.edtTableCount);
            String getTableCount = edtTableCount.getText().toString();
            int tableCount = Integer.parseInt(getTableCount);

            for (int i = 0; i< tableCount; i++){

                dataModelList.add(new DataModel(new ArrayList<>(),"Masa " + i));

            }

            edtTableCount.setVisibility(GONE);
            btnCreateTable.setVisibility(GONE);
            recylerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        });

        setAdapter();


    }

    public void setAdapter(){

        CustomItemClickListener listener = (v, position) -> {

            Intent i = new Intent(TableActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("position",position);
            i.putExtra("dataModelList",dataModelList);

            startActivity(i);

        };

        adapter = new TableAdapter(this,dataModelList,listener);
        recylerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
```

**DetailsActivity.Java**

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<DataModel> dataModelList = new ArrayList<>();

    DataModel dataModel;
    EditText edtDeviceInfo, edtBrand, edtModel, edtProcessor, edtRam, edtGraphicCard, edtOperationSystem, edtHardDisc, edtPrograms, edtDescription;
    Button btnAdd;

    int position = 0;

    String keyDeviceInfo = "keyDeviceInfo",
            keyBrand = "keyBrand",
            keyModel = "keyModel",
            keyProcessor = "keyModel",
            keyRam = "keyModel",
            keyGraphicCard = "keyModel",
            keyOperationSystem = "keyModel",
            keyHardDisc = "keyModel",
            keyPrograms = "keyModel",
            keyDescription = "keyModel"
            ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        edtDeviceInfo = findViewById(R.id.edtDeviceInfo);
        edtBrand = findViewById(R.id.edtBrand);
        edtModel = findViewById(R.id.edtModel);
        edtProcessor = findViewById(R.id.edtProcessor);
        edtRam = findViewById(R.id.edtRam);
        edtGraphicCard = findViewById(R.id.edtGraphicCard);
        edtOperationSystem = findViewById(R.id.edtOperationSystem);
        edtHardDisc = findViewById(R.id.edtHardDisc);
        edtPrograms = findViewById(R.id.edtPrograms);
        edtDescription = findViewById(R.id.edtDescription);
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        dataModelList = (DataModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dataModelList");
        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
        dataModel = dataModelList.get(position);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            setInformations(

                    edtDeviceInfo.getText().toString(),
                    edtBrand.getText().toString(),
                    edtModel.getText().toString(),
                    edtProcessor.getText().toString(),
                    edtRam.getText().toString(),
                    edtGraphicCard.getText().toString(),
                    edtOperationSystem.getText().toString(),
                    edtHardDisc.getText().toString(),
                    edtPrograms.getText().toString(),
                    edtDescription.getText().toString()

            );

        });

    }

    public void setInformations(String deviceInfo, String brand, String model, String processor, String ram, String graphiccard, String operationsystem,
                                String harddisc, String programs, String description){

        edtDeviceInfo.setText(deviceInfo);
        edtBrand.setText(brand);
        edtModel.setText(model);
        edtProcessor.setText(processor);
        edtRam.setText(ram);
        edtGraphicCard.setText(graphiccard);
        edtOperationSystem.setText(operationsystem);
        edtHardDisc.setText(harddisc);
        edtPrograms.setText(programs);
        edtDescription.setText(description);

    }

}
```

Comment: You are adding a single `DataModel` item to the Intent, but trying to get a `ArrayList<DataModel>` in the receiver `Activity` - the error tells you exactly this. just cast to a `(DataModel)` instead (with no need to add the position extra). Note - adding code snippets to your question is generally good practice rather than links to screen shots of code.

Comment: You are passing `dataModelList.get(position)` -- a single **DataModel** object via intent, and retrieving the `ArrayList<DataModel>` in the receiver activity; instead of `DataModel`. What data you need? Whole list or single object? Based on that pass appropriate value to the intent.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand how to put the codes clearly. I tried a few many times but the codes were messed up.

Let me explain what I need. I'm using a recyclerview to create tables in application. Afterwards, I made an activity to set details for tables.

Example : Table 0 -> cpu - gpu - os - etc.

I want to check the position to find Which on table I am. Then I'll set some extra features per table. I'll try to put codes into the main comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing object on intent by doing this,

```
i.putExtra("dataModelList", dataModelList.get(position))

 // dataModelList.get(position) here you are not fetching the list but rather getting single object from list based on position. So, it's object not ArrayList.
```

and on receiver side, you are expecting `ArrayList`.
It should be like this

```
dataModel = (DataModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("dataModelList");
```

Answer (score 0):

from activity
pass array from activity one or adapter

```
Intent i=new Intent(context, NewsActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)model);
            bundle.putString("position", String.valueOf(position));
            i.putExtra("BUNDLE",bundle);
            context.startActivity(i);
```

and on second activity
Receive passed array to second activity like this.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
    flipdatalist = (ArrayList<FlipModel>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
        position= Integer.parseInt(args.getString("position"));
```